# Applying A-weighting

Tags: algorithms, audio

I want to calculate the loudness of a given signal and I've come across [this thread](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/290/getting-loudness-of-a-track-with-rms). I'm slightly confused about the A-Weighting aspect of it. I can't post images, but I think [this site](http://www.diracdelta.co.uk/science/source/a/w/aweighting/source.html) has the formula I need. (Wa = 10log...)

What I don't understand is how to actually use it in my program. If the `f` stands for frequency, then presumably I can hardcode the values since they will remain constant. If that is the case, how do I apply `Wa` to my sample values and what values do I use? Do I calculate the power spectrum to get `WINDOW_SIZE/2` values and multiply each value in the frequency band with relevant precalculated `Wa` value or is that the wrong way of doing it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you could hardcode the values, do an FFT of your signal, and multiply by the hardcoded values, then [get the amplitude in the frequency domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/346/rms-calculation-in-frequency-domain-after-windowing) from [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) ([example](https://gist.github.com/1257010)).

You could also implement a digital filter and do it in the time domain.  Here's [Matlab code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69) and [my translation to Python](https://gist.github.com/148112).

Note that the bilinear transform causes the digital filter to roll-off more quickly than the analog filter, introducing measurement errors at common sample rates. A simple fix is to upsample the data first, so the discrepancy is minimized. Other filter design approaches here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36077/29

Comment: Thanks, I'm understanding it a bit better. In your Parseval example, is rms_flat the RMS equation `(SQRT(x1^2 + x2^2...xn^2/n))` and what's the difference between rms_flat of the signal and rms_flat of the FFT?

Comment: @ExpAns: Yes, `rms_flat()` is just `sqrt(mean(absolute(a)**2))`.  The `/n` is on the outside.  The RMS value of the signal and FFT are the same except for a scaling factor.